# Рендер отдельного компонента React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Постараюсь правильно описать вопрос.

Есть родительский компонет в котором два дочерних.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <Search /> // компоненn для поиска который содержит только input и кнопку НАЙТИ
      <Main /> // компонет данных корорые должны отрисовываться по поиску
    </div>
  }
}
```

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку **НАЙТИ** перерисовывался (рендерился) только компонент , чтобы текст (value) из инпута компонента **Search** не пропадал и соответственно компонет не мигал при рендеринге?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так: [пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/9l5qoxq59y)

Суть в чем: вы храните значение `input` в родительском компоненте в `state`. При изменении значения меняете `state`. При нажатии на кнопку, так же в родительском компоненте получаете список отфильтрованных элементов и их уже пробрасываете в компонент `Main`

`index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import Main from "./Main";
import Search from "./Search";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    search: "",
    result: []
  };

  handleChangeSearch = ({ target }) => {
    this.setState({
      search: target.search
    });
  };

  handleSearch = () => {
    this.setState({
      result: [
        { id: 1, name: "Результат 1" },
        { id: 2, name: "Результат 2" },
        { id: 3, name: "Результат 3" },
        { id: 4, name: "Результат 4" },
        { id: 5, name: "Результат 5" }
      ]
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { search, result } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Search
          value={search}
          onChange={this.handleChangeSearch}
          onSubmit={this.handleSearch}
        />
        <Main items={result} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогли.